# Activity Processor issue with Caldera Forms

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms

Using 
Wp 4.9.8
Caldera 1.74
Caldera Forms CiviCRM 0.4.4

I'm struggling to work out how to expose the activity fields (core and custom) to the layout area once I've added an Activity processor to the form.

I'm using the template for creating two contacts with a relationship, but I need to collect some info and kick off an activity as well, so how do I add the extra fields?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I worked this one out. You have to create the fields in the Caldera form first and then match CiviFields in the processor you've added to the Caldera fields you've created, it's a bit like mapping fields for import

Comment: We have [documentation on here](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm/tree/master/docs) as part of plugin repo

Comment: That feels a bit hidden.